# More finer-grained control in nextjs router caching

Tags: next.js, next.js13

This is a two folder question. First, a bit of background: My usecase for nextjs is a heavy, dynamic user dashboard application.

Dynamic in the sense of client side updates of data. And it being a user-scoped means there is authentication involved. My usage of RSC is fairly minimal, but I do rely on SSR for populating the initial state of the dashboard which is then rehydrated and finalized on the client-side. The initial state of the dashboard is populated by fetching the user details from an external api in the top-level RSC page.

On the server, I am utilizing "force-dynamic" to disable caching and minimize build-time generated artifacts, and while this solves most of the immediate issues, there is some annoying behaviours that I would like to be resolved.

##### Client-side app router

My research has led me to the fact that the app router caches dynamic pages for 30 seconds. Is it possible to increase this or even cache indefinitely? I don't really need nextjs to go to the server again since most of the updates to the UI is done on the client. Once a page is retrieved from the router, it should be cached indefinitely.

##### Server side re-validation

Depending on what the outcome is with the point above, this may not be an immediate issue. But everytime 30secs expire and nextjs goes back to the server to revalidate the page, the code that is run to fetch the user details is being executed over and over again. What is the "correct" way to handle this? Is it possible to inform nextjs to just stop revalidating?